# iOS app how to submit using client's profile

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8

We are developing an iOS app and we are using our company iOS Dev account (our provisioning profile) for that.

Now the client wants to submit the app using his Apple account.

If our client doesn't have a Mac I think we'll have to create the ipa file and send him. But I'm not sure how I can create the distribution file using their provisioning profile.

Can you please explain what is the process followed in this kind of a scenario?

Do I need to create another apple account and add it to the client's iOS Dev account and create the ipa file using that provisioning profile or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Your client can invite you to their dev team. This will give you access to the provisioning profiles (if you have the correct permission level).

Comment: Ok thanks. So can I use the same Apple account I am using to connect to our company dev account?

Comment: To answer my question, client created an email account for me and gave that necessary permissions under their dev account and iTunes account and I submitted using that account. First I tried with my Apple Id, but it doesn't allow me to use the same Apple Id in two iTunes accounts. So the client had to create a new Apple Id for this.

Answer (score 0):

Superb Question.I have stuck with this lot of times.After that i made me doing very simple and easy.

1. The first thing is you have create the App Id for your application in

   -> Developer.apple.com

   -> Member Center

   -> Click certificates

   -> where you can see the app id (It is in left side of the window).If you click app id in center page you can see the old app id's.

   -> In above click + symbol for adding new app id for your app
2. Go to key chain access.If you do not find out that,just enter in spot light.It will come.

   ->Click the key chain access and go to toolbar of the Mac

   ->where you can see the **Apple Symbol,Keychain Access,File,Edit,View,Window,Help**

   ->Click **Keychain access**

   ->Then Click **Certificate Assistant**

   once you click that you can see the options.

   ->Then click **Request a Certificate from certificate Authority**.

   ->Now **Certificate information** box opens.

   ->Give **user email address**

   ->Then click **save to disk** only.

   Now if you see the desktop,there is CSR.It is used for creating developer and distribution.

   3.Go to developer.apple.com site

   ```
   -> Member Center

   -> Click certificates
   ```

   4. Click  **Developer Certificate**

      ->Click **+** add button

      ->Select **IOS Apple Development** for Developer Provisional Certificate

      ->It asks you **CSR** for the Generating Developer Certificate

      ->Just **choose from Desktop**.

      ->Click **Generate**

      ->Double Click for **Download**

      ->If you give the correct CSR it shows developer certificate in keychain with key.
   5. Click **Production Certificate**

      ->Click **+** add button

      ->Select **IOS Apple Adhoc Distribution** for Distribution Provisional Certificate

      ->It asks you CSR**strong text** for the Generating Production  Certificate

      ->Just choose from **Desktop**.

      ->Click **Generate**

      ->Double Click for **Download**

      ->If you give the correct CSR it shows production certificate in keychain with key
   6. Click **Development Provisional** for running the app in device(It is in left below of the window)

      ->Click **+** button.It is on above.

      ->**Choose your app id from list app id list**  (drop down list)

      ->Then Give the **name to development provisional**

      ->Select or Choose the **Development Certificate**

      ->Also Choose or **Select all devices or particular your client device**

      ->Then **submit**(generate and done)

      ->Click **Download**

      ->After that **Double Click** the downloaded certificate.

      ->If you check in **xcode (Click project and choose Build Setting -> click code signing)**

      ->First choose your **provisional certificate**(Your downloaded development certificate is appearing just select that)

      ->After that click **Code Signing Identity**  and select the Developer Certificate from the list

      ->Finally **Targets**-Code Signing

      ->First choose your **provisional certificate**(Your downloaded development certificate is appearing just select that)

      ->After that click **Code Signing Identity** and select the Developer Certificate
   7. Click **Distribution Provisional** for running the app in required devices(It is in left below of the window)

      ->Click **+** button.It is on above.

      ->**Choose your app id from list app id list  (drop down list)**

      ->**Then Give the name to Distribution Provisional**

      ->Select or Choose the **Production Certificate**

      ->Also Choose or **Select all devices or particular your client device**

      ->Then **submit**(generate and done)

      ->Click **Download**

      ->After that **Double Click** the downloaded certificate.

      ->If you check in **xcode (Click project and choose Build Setting -> click code signing)**

      ->First choose your **provisional certificate**(Your downloaded distribution certificate is appearing just select that)

      ->After that click **Code Signing Identity** and select the Distribution Certificate

      ->Finally **Targets-Code Signing**

      ->First choose your provisional certificate(Your downloaded distribution certificate is appearing just select that)

      ->After that click **Code Signing Identity** and select the Production Certificate
   8. Finally **Archive** this for ipa.

   NOTE - **Give the Correct App Id in .plist Then only it accepts and run.**